# Where does FireFox-10 hide the URL Favicon relationship?

Tags: firefox, tabs, favicon, address-bar

We use CentOS-6, a RedHat EL6 distro rebuild, and this ships with FireFox-10.0.12 ESR.  We recently changed the favicon.ico image on several internal servers.  Actually we just provided the corporate favicon to those sites that had none.

Now, the difficulty is this.  When a FF user who visited a given url before the favicon was provided now visits that url following the update then the new favicon is not displayed in either their URL address bar or in the tab for that page.  Instead they see that dashed box outline indicating that no favicon is present.

However, when a FF user who had never previously visited that same url does so then that FF instance does display the new favicon in both the address bar and tab on that FF browser.

I have looked into this briefly and frankly was astounded at how common this problem appears to be and the absolute lack of any sensible response to the issue even on Mozilla's own support forums.  I have tried hacking and picking at the places.sqlite store but even deleting the entire places.sqlite file or emptying the favicon tables and restarting firefox does not solve the problem of displaying a changed favicon the tab and url icon display.  All that does is hammer the user's bookmarks.

Now I can, and have, resorted to the trick of adding `<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico">` in the `<head></head>` block of those urls that use static pages but some are generated dynamically by third-party applications. These urls do not offer a convenient method to make this modification to their output.

Where does FireFox-10 cache the favicon for a newly visited url and how does one remove that reference from the user's profile?

Answer (score 0):

A browser does not necessarily request a fresh copy of the /favicon.ico (or an icon specified by a meta tag) *on each visit*. Once it has a favicon (or thinks there isn't one), it is often some time before it will request an update (this depends on the particular browser). I have had *some* success with unbookmarking a site and clearing the browser cache.